# How to transpose result?

Tags: sql, transpose, presto

I have this query

```
Select week(date_time) week,
      sum(X1) as X1,
      sum(X2) as X2,
      sum(X3) as X3,
      sum(X4) as X4
From Fee
Where date_time between '2020-07-01' and current_date
```

I got result as below:

```
week | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
27   |
28   |
29   |
30   |
31   |
```

But I would like to transpose the result like:

```
week | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31
X1   |
X2   |
X3   |
X4   |
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to unpivot the data and re-aggregate:

```
select v.x,
       sum(case when week(date_time) = 27 then 1 else 0 end) as week_27,
       sum(case when week(date_time) = 28 then 1 else 0 end) as week_28,
       sum(case when week(date_time) = 29 then 1 else 0 end) as week_29,
       sum(case when week(date_time) = 30 then 1 else 0 end) as week_30,
       sum(case when week(date_time) = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as week_31
from fee f left join lateral
     (values (f.x1), (f.x2), (f.x3), (f.x4)) v(x)
group by v.x
```

Presto also supports `filter`, so this is better written as:

```
select v.x,
       count(*) filter (where week(date_time) = 27) as week_27,
       count(*) filter (where week(date_time) = 28) as week_28,
       count(*) filter (where week(date_time) = 29) as week_29,
       count(*) filter (where week(date_time) = 30) as week_30,
       count(*) filter (where week(date_time) = 31) as week_31
from fee f left join lateral
     (values (f.x1), (f.x2), (f.x3), (f.x4)) v(x)
group by v.x
```

Comment: You can use filtered aggregations: `count() FILTER (WHERE week(date_time) = 27) AS week_27, ...`. See docs @ https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it impossible for date_time running from 35 days ago to the current date? Cause your code, the week time is fixed.

Comment: @JJJJJ . . . That would be a different question.  I think this question is pretty clearly about fixed dates.